# Software i2C communication protocol "MikroC for Pic" halting problem

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, uart, microchip

I work with Pic16f688 , and i do a soft i2C

***MikroC for pic compiler does not supply its libraries functions code***

***this is the whole code i use for MCU***

```
sbit   dataReady    at     PORTC.b1 ;
sbit   LEDup        at     PORTA.b0;
sbit   LEDdown      at     PORTA.b1;
sbit   LED          at     PORTC.b2;


// Software I2C connections
sbit Soft_I2C_Scl           at RA5_bit;
sbit Soft_I2C_Sda           at RA4_bit;
sbit Soft_I2C_Scl_Direction at TRISA5_bit;
sbit Soft_I2C_Sda_Direction at TRISA4_bit;

// End Software I2C connections

unsigned short int i=0;
unsigned short int Data[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
unsigned short int responce[5];
//########################################################################

void main()
{
  OSCTUNE.TUN4=1;
  OSCTUNE.TUN3=1;
  OSCTUNE.TUN2=1;
  OSCTUNE.TUN1=1;
  OSCTUNE.TUN0=1;
  OSCCON.SCS=1;
  OSCCON.IRCF0=0;
  OSCCON.IRCF1=0;
  OSCCON.IRCF2=1;
  UART1_Init(9600);
  Delay_ms(10);// Wait for UART module to stabilize

/*INTCON.INTE=0;
  INT0Enable=1;
  OPTION_REG.INTEDG=0;
  INTCON.GIE=1;
  INTCON.INTE=1;*/
  /*WDTCON.WDTPS3=0;
  WDTCON.WDTPS2=1;
  WDTCON.WDTPS1=1;
  WDTCON.WDTPS0=1;
  WDTCON.SWDTEN=1;*/
  ANSEL=0b00000000;
  CMCON0.CM0=1;
  CMCON0.CM1=1;
  CMCON0.CM2=1;
  ADCON0.VCFG=0;
  ADCON0.ADON=0;
  TRISC0_bit=0 ;
  TRISC1_bit=1 ;//dataReady
  TRISC2_bit=0 ;
  TRISC3_bit=0 ;
  TRISA0_bit=0 ;
  TRISA1_bit=0 ;
 //Timer0_Function();

 INTCON.GIE=0;
 Soft_I2C_Init();
 Delay_ms(500);
    /*Soft_I2C_Start();
     Soft_I2C_Write(0x9A);
         Soft_I2C_Write(0x55);  Soft_I2C_Write(0x01);Soft_I2C_Write(0x12);
     Soft_I2C_Stop();*/
    /* Soft_I2C_Start();
     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
      if(i==4)responce[i]=Soft_I2C_Read(0);
      else responce[i]=Soft_I2C_Read(1);
     }
     Soft_I2C_Stop();*/
   LEDup=0;
   LEDdown=1;
   LED=1;
  while(1)
  {
     Delay_ms(2000);
  //higher_byte=0x1E;  UART1_Write(higher_byte) ;
/*if(dataReady==1)
   {
     //UART1_Write(0x11);
     Soft_I2C_Start();
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
       if(i<5)Data[i]=Soft_I2C_Read(0);
       else Data[i]=Soft_I2C_Read(1);
     }
     Soft_I2C_Stop();
   }
   else
   {
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
      while(UART1_Tx_Idle()==0) { }
      UART1_Write(Data[i]) ;
    }
   }*/

          UART1_Write(0x11) ;

           //asm{CLRWDT}
  }

 }

//##############################################################################
```

but this doen't work ,so any help or suggestions pls 
it doesn't work as the program flow is halting 
after those lines i say to MCU the following

```
sbit   LED          at     PORTC.b2;
LED=1;
```

i expect  to see the led is up but nothing work , i checked every connection , but in vain . that is why i say it doesn't work at the first place.

Further more 
i wanted to make sure that not a hardware connection  is the reason  ,so 
i used USART terminal to display some bytes in the terminal , i write those lines after the i2C code lines above:

```
UART1_Write(0x11) ;
```

so when i comment the i2C code i get 0x11 in the terminal , when i uncomment them , everything is halted !

Also , when i comment the i2C lines led is up , otherwise is down  .

deleting all soft i2c code and just leaving                  `Soft_I2C_Init();` is enough to halt the flow of the program

***THIS IS AR1020 datasheet*** http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41393A.pdf

***note***

In circuit design ,the two pins in MCU used for soft_i2C is not connected to pull up resistor as in hardware i2C pins

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are going to have to roll up your sleeves and dig into software debug which will require a good understanding of the I2C protocol and likely even an oscilloscope to check the waveforms and timings. You generally cannot expect some code that you download off some arbitrary site on the internet to be fully functional in your application (especially code that operates I/O like this.

Comment: Deleting your question and creating an identical one is very frowned upon. You have not even addressed the issue I pointed out on your other question. I see no source for the software I2C functions and therefore I can do nothing to help you solve your issue. This time around I will also add that, when seeking out code assistance, it is counterproductive to give a full program that is all in one function. A minimal example is far more likely to get attention. I recommend you remove what is not essential to your example (ex. test code in comments, unrelated code, ...).

Comment: I write it down on my own , not from site on internet .

Comment: I don't understand what u mean , I added the whole code I used on MCU which cause the problem , so what  do u want else ?

Comment: I didn't delete it and write it same again . I modified it and I remove the unnecessary comments and texts

Comment: Tell me exactly what u want , which I2C functions code u want?

Comment: Your previous questions ID#219753 : This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: If u mean that u want the code of the I2C functions , this is a built in functions in mikroC for pic .!!!!! I didn't write them down , I just use the library !!!

Comment: And there is nothing not related to the code now , I removed all unnecessary thing .the rest of comments are belonging to the problem and  to my question . Read well before voting -1

Comment: One issue with mikroElektronika's compilers it that they keep their libraries closed-source, so source code is not visible to users.

Comment: Do you have pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL?

Comment: No, i say that in the end of question above ,with photo . I didn't put them because they are soft I2C ,so the used 2 pins actually not open drain

Comment: @AndrejaKo yes .tell him please

Comment: I humbly admit that I was not aware of the closed source nature of the library. The rest of my comment stands. Your code still contains large swaths of commented and/or unrelated code and your deleting your previous question to recreate it does not encourage a helping hand.

Comment: All code above contain I2C USART and MCU configuration registers even the commented parts are related , read well pls

Comment: I2C is *ALWAYS* open-drain. it doesn't matter if you're using hardware I2C or 'soft I2C'. You *MUST* have pullup resistors on your SDA and SCL lines. If you don't then that's the most likely reason for Soft_I2C_Init() to be hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AhmedZainElDein,

> In circuit design ,the two pins in MCU used for soft_i2C is not
>   connected to pull up resistor as in hardware i2C pins

Some parts of your description are not clear (at least to me), but reading other parts of your question, one problem (and answer) is clear - **add pull-up resistors** to the SCL and SDA pins.

Even though your PIC16F688 does not have open-drain (OD) output options, the standard way to emulate OD pins is for software to switch between actively driving the output pin low, and switching that pin to be an input (allowing the external pull-up resistor to pull the pin high).  Also the I2C slave(s) still need the pull-up resistors since they cannot pull those signals high.*

[* Except the few newer, faster I2C spec devices, which use push-pull drivers - this does not apply here.]

> deleting all soft i2c code and just leaving Soft_I2C_Init(); is enough
>   to halt the flow of the program

Yes, this is expected. The Soft I2C library will be waiting for the SCL pin to go high and will wait until that happens.  Below link is an example of exactly this situation (no pull-up resistors and call to Soft_I2C_Init() hangs) on the MikroE forum [[1](http://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=25939)] - notice that the fix is to **add pull-up resistors** to the SCL and SDA pins:

http://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=25939

Also the need for pull-up resistors is explained in the docs for the Soft I2C library here:

http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/software_i2c_library.htm

Where it says:

> The pins used for the Software I²C communication should be connected
>   to the pull-up resistors

and

> All I²C Library functions are blocking-call functions (they are
>   waiting for I²C clock line to become logical one).

So that is why your code hangs, without pull-up resistors.

There might be other problems with your code [I don't have time to go through it all] and in any work with I2C then I have always found an oscilloscope (and/or logic analyser) to be useful or sometimes vital. After adding the pull-up resistors (choosing the best value of those is helped by viewing the signals with a 'scope - I suggest you start with 4k7 pull-ups, but other people may suggest different starting values) then your call to Soft_I2C_Init() should no longer hang. Good luck.

Comment: thank u it works , can u give me a simple piece of code to show how is the right way to communicate with AR1020 in soft i2c read and write

Comment: @AhmedZainElDein,

(a) No, I don't have example code for you. I was able to answer your original question using I2C knowledge and experience (confirmed by the Google results which I supplied), but I don't have an AR1020 here to test any code - and I don't want to give you untested code;

(b) FYI the AR1020 is shown by Microchip as "not recommended for new designs";

(c) FYI, looking at the updated rev B of the datasheet which you linked in your question http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41393B.pdf which includes details of the newer AR1021, it describes that [...]

Comment: [...] the AR1021 will use SCL clock-stretching when doing some types of I2C I/O (section 4.6). However the older AR1020 does not implement clock-stretching and requires the programmer to add a 50us delay before sending the Stop bit (section 4.7). This will be relevant to you, if you want to try using the AR1020; (d) Now that your original question has been resolved, I believe that any new questions you have, should be new topics and not mixed in with this one :-)